# Extjs Treepanel: CSS to change default icons (node and leaf)

Tags: extjs, tree, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have a tree panel like **http://jsfiddle.net/bmbMy/**
I try to change default icons (node and leaf) by using css. But that not working.

```
.x-grid-row  .x-grid-tree-node-expanded {
    background: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/sekkyumu/developpers/16/Play-Green-Button-icon.png') no-repeat center center !important;
}
.x-grid-row  .x-grid-tree-node-leaf {
    background-image:url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicrating/koloria/16/Button-Play-Pause-icon.png');
}
```

How can i do that thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't override the right css classes. Here is what you need:

```
.x-grid-tree-node-expanded .x-tree-icon-parent {
    background: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/sekkyumu/developpers/16/Play-Green-Button-icon.png') no-repeat center center !important;
}
.x-grid-row  .x-tree-icon-leaf {
    background-image:url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicrating/koloria/16/Button-Play-Pause-icon.png');
}
```

And the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmbMy/1/).

Comment: +1 .. I noticed that if you don't have any custom styles, the load mask shows when the decedent tree nodes are loading.  Is there a way to customize the mask so it uses the default load mask like it does without these styles?  Without the load mask, it's difficult to tell when nodes are loading, especially when it's recursive.