# Load specific icons in tree.Panel depending on node type

Tags: extjs, tree

I am begining in Extjs and i would like to make a tree (with tree.Panel) which contents both file and folder.
 Moreover I would like to display specific icons for each type of node : a file must not have a folder child so the icon "create folder" which must only appear on folder nodes.
I already have a tree with a boutton "delete" which exists for both types.

I presume I must listen for a event like "renderer" and ask for the type of my node and load the corresponding icon but I don't know how to do : the event comes from a different column that the tree column.

How can I get the node type (leaf:true/false) from the actionColumn which will content the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please elaborate your question.
If it is related to getting the node type(leaf or not) all you have to do is to add a renderer function to your column as below

```
              {
                    text: 'View in Filters',
                    flex: 2,
                    renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
                      if(record.data.leaf){
                           //Do your stuff 
                         }
                       else {
                          //Do something else.
                           }
                    }
```

Or if it is related to  showing  different icons for  parent and children check this once

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631880/extjs-treepanel-css-to-change-default-icons-node-and-leaf
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you! It what I wanted to know...I am realy begining in extjs and event handling is a bit strange for me.